# Auth0 passwordless with google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jwt, auth0

I'm using auth0 to authenticate users from my google chrome extension. in my main app I'm using passwordless and I want to use the same with chrome extension. I just couldn't find out how!

[Here is the documentation that I'm following](https://github.com/auth0/lock-passwordless)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`auth0-chrome`](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-chrome) package, which also uses the Universal Login (previous "Hosted Pages"/"Hosted Login").

Note that you need to create a `Native` type application in your auth0 tenant and then provide that application's ID for the extension (in your background script's message listener).

The easiest way to read the repo's readme is to first read "Using the Library" (since that section explains the tenant setup and configuring the callback URLs, etc.) and then going through the "Usage" section (actual code examples).